# How to locate incoming email document library in sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, document-library, incoming-email

I set up multiple incoming email document libraries in SharePoint 2007 a long time ago. Now  I have forgotten where those document libraries are!

How can I locate them altogether (which emails and to which document libraries)?

Answer (score 1):

Through PowerShell, of course!  SharePoint 2007 does not include all the nifty cmdlets that SharePoint 2010/2013 does but you can still access the full object model.  MSDN has a link on how to get started with [PowerShell in SharePoint 2007](http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2013/01/22/running-powershell-on-moss-2007.aspx).

Once you have that, it is just a matter of writing the script, which would be something *like* this:

```
$site = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite]("url.to.site.com")
$site.AllWebs | % {
   $_.Lists | % {
      if ($_.CanReceiveEmail -eq $true -and $_.EmailAlias -eq "myemail@site.com") {
         $_.DefaultViewUrl
      }
   }
   $_.Dispose()
}
$site.Dispose()
```

This would return the list of URLs to the lists where that email is used.  If you want, you can also change the EmailAlias part to `$_.EmailAlias -ne $null` instead to return a list of all email enabled lists.